# Keep getting injection modulerr error on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I use the following code to create an angular app, using routes and controllers.

```
(function() {
    angular.module('eCommerceApp', ['ngRoute'])
        .config('$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
                when('/', {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/phonelist.html',
                    controller: 'mobilePhoneListController'
                }).
                when('/phone/:phoneSlug', {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/phonedetail.html',
                    controller: 'mobilePhoneDetailController'
                }).
                otherwise({
                    templateUrl: 'error/404.html',
                });
        })
        .controller('mobilePhoneListController', ['$http', function($http) {
            var thisObj = this;
            thisObj.mobilePhones = [];

            $http.get('/api/getallphones').then( function(data) {
                thisObj.mobilePhones = data;
            }, function(data) {
                thisObj.mobilePhones = data || "Request Data Fail!";
            });
        }])
        .controller('mobilePhoneDetailController', ['$http', function($http) {
            var thisObj = this;
        }])
})();
```

Before that I imported 3 scripts. Angular, angular-route and my app

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="/angular/e-commerce-app.js"></script>
```

and the website main structure

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="eCommerceApp">
<!-- ... -->
<body ng-view>
</body>
</html>
```

also tried with `<ng-view></ng-view>`

But I always seam to get [this error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=eCommerceApp&p1=Error:%20%5Bng:areq%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.8%2Fng%2Fareq%3Fp0%3Dfn%26p1%3Dnot%2520a%2520function%252C%2520got%2520string%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:6:416%0A%20%20%20%20at%20qb%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:22:131)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Qa%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:22:218)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Function.eb.$$annotate%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:185:222)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.e%20%5Bas%20invoke%5D%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:39:226)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:38:64)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:38:188%0A%20%20%20%20at%20n%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:7:333)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:37:488).

> Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error
>   Failed to instantiate module eCommerceApp due to:
>   Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20...
>      at Error (native)
>      at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:6:416
>   ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't include the `.config` file right. I implemented it using

```
.config('$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) { ... });
```

while it should've been

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) { ... }]);
```

(notice the `[]`)

Answer (score 1):

In your website main structure (index.html), use ng-app="eCommerceApp" as an attribute in 'body' tag. For example:

```
<body ng-app="eCommerceApp">
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot to put that in, but I already have ng-app in html, I'll edit now. The app worked all until I implemented routes.

Comment: This question is answered in this post. Check it. Might be useful for you. Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363020/angularjs-error-injector-modulerr?rq=1

Comment: Nah, I figured it out, I'll leave an answer in case someone runs into this problem as well.